# Rebuild of xDb index gets stuck in finishing stage at 95%

Tags: indexing

We are trying to rebuild our xDB index and every time it gets to 95% done in the finishing stage. The only place I have found this is [this post](https://www.unravelsitecore.com/tag/rebuild-xdb-index/). But it is Azure based and does not really apply because the setting talked about was not set to this large number (It was still set to the default). I have a ticket with Sitecore support but they basically have no idea yet.

Here is what the indexer logs.

```
2022-02-12 16:59:36.566 -06:00 [Warning] Timed out while doing a graceful shut down of the rebuild monitoring task.
2022-02-12 16:59:37.145 -06:00 [Information] Starting Xdb Indexer App Domain, Machine: 123, InstanceName: XConnectIndexer_AppDomain
2022-02-12 16:59:37.966 -06:00 [Information] SystemPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:XConnectIndexer, Path: App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json
2022-02-12 16:59:38.604 -06:00 [Information] Indexing has started
2022-02-12 16:59:38.604 -06:00 [Information] Monitoring rebuild requests.
2022-02-12 16:59:38.729 -06:00 [Information] Resuming index rebuild.
2022-02-12 16:59:38.782 -06:00 [Information] Rebuilding process. Stage: RebuildingExistingData.
Total progress: 84.15%.
Stage progress: 99.00%.
2022-02-12 16:59:38.845 -06:00 [Information] Rebuilding process. Stage: RebuildingExistingData.
Total progress: 85.00%.
Stage progress: 100.00%.
2022-02-12 16:59:38.860 -06:00 [Information] Rebuilding process. Stage: RebuildingIncomingChanges.
Total progress: 85.00%.
Stage progress: 0.00%.
2022-02-12 16:59:39.350 -06:00 [Information] Rebuilding process. Stage: RebuildingIncomingChanges.
Total progress: 95.00%.
Stage progress: 100.00%.
2022-02-12 16:59:39.366 -06:00 [Information] Rebuilding process. Stage: Finishing.
Total progress: 95.00%.
Stage progress: 0.00%.
2022-02-12 16:59:39.366 -06:00 [Information] Shutting down
2022-02-12 16:59:39.803 -06:00 [Information] Shutting down
2022-02-12 16:59:48.731 -06:00 [Information] Rebuilding process. Stage: Finishing.
Total progress: 95.00%.
Stage progress: 0.00%.
2022-02-12 16:59:48.731 -06:00 [Information] Shutting down
2022-02-12 17:00:14.808 -06:00 [Warning] Timed out while doing a graceful shut down of the rebuild monitoring task.
```

At this it just keeps looping on this chunk of logs over and over for hours and hours.

Comment: I could only get past this by stopping the indexing of anonymous contacts. We have 5 million contacts in total.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisAuer. We have anonymous indexing turned off and have ~90 million contacts. We made a change to add a DoNotIndex attribute to a couple of facets and that is when this started.

Comment: Ah ok. I think it is a size issue. I would contact support. I was on support when I had this issue and turning off anonymous allowed it to complete for us.